# Different Token Expiration Depending of Client Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel application that uses Passport authentication.

**Login**

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 1,
        'client_secret' => "secret",
        'username' => request('username'),
        'password' => request('password'),
        'active' => 1,
        'scope' => '*'
    ];

    $request->request->add($params);

    // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

I have settled the expiration on **AuthServiceProvider**:

```
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
   $router->forAccessTokens();
});
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinute(1));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
```

It works but after 1 minute the token expires. I want a different expiration date for token depending on where I'm trying to make login because I have a website, desktop app and an Android app.

For example:

- web app: 8 hours
- desktop app: 1 Year
- android app: 5 months

I was thinking send me from where I'm trying to make the login, but is that a good way? Are there any other possible ways to do it?

For now I have tried this:

-) deleted From AuthServiceProvider:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinute(1));
```

And added in Login function:

```
if (request('from') == 'something') {
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addYears(1));
} else {
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addHours(8));
}

$proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
```

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with your way. Maybe you can use something like https://github.com/jenssegers/agent to the User Agent validation, instead of sending something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get help from below link please find

[For getting user agent detail and apply condition base on agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent)

for example you can use code like below

```
if ( Agent::isDesktop() ) {
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addYears(1));
} else if(Agent::isMobile()){
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMonth(5));
}else{
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addHours(8));
}
```

Comment: passport token expiry not working... supposed My expiry limit is 30 min and i logged into at 12:00 then session will get expired at 12:30.. in between I'm updating the expires_at  in oauth_access_token table on every activity. So, expired_at time will get extends.. ex. my last hit on 12:15 then token will expire on 12:45.. but i dont know how still token get expire at 12:30.. can you please suggest a way? Due to this facing issue in web app that i got logout during inprogress activity. please help

Comment: @Rakhi please share your code snippet. so that i can get what you have done so far